# How to get correctly an element inside url

Tags: php

I have this url (norma)

```
http://localhost/test/boutique/index.php?language=fr
```

When I rewrite url I have this (no rewriting rules) I have this

```
http://localhost/test/boutique/index.php/language,fr
```

When I want to change my language :
In the first case work perfectly but the secondy does'nt work.

Do you have any idea to take the fr of this `language,fr`.

my code

`isset($_GET['language']` is always on false

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['language']) || isset($_GET['language'])) {
    if (isset($_GET['language']) && !empty($_GET['language']) && $OSCOM_Language->exists($_GET['language'])) {
      $OSCOM_Language->set($_GET['language']);
    }

    $_SESSION['language'] = $OSCOM_Language->get('code'); // default language
  }
```

Tk.

Comment: language !=anguage but other than that `$_GET` is correct

Comment: The `l`  is missing in `?anguage=fr`

Comment: I think OP has a keyboard with a dodgy `L` key, its missing in a number of places LOL

Comment: confirm missing l , change

Comment: @RiggsFolly an idea ?